# How to combine GridSearchCV and SelectFromModel to reduce the number of features?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm trying to run QSAR using sklearn and pandas.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
FC_data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Dre\\Desktop\\My Papers\\Furocoumarins_paper_2018\\Furocoumarins_NEW1.xlsx', index_col=0)
FC_data.head()

# Create correlation matrix
corr_matrix = FC_data.corr().abs()
# Select upper triangle of correlation matrix
upper = corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(np.bool))
# Find index of feature columns with correlation greater than 0.95
to_drop = [column for column in upper.columns if any(upper[column] > 0.95)]
# Drop features 
FC_data1 = FC_data.drop(FC_data[to_drop], axis=1)

y = FC_data1.LogFiT
X = FC_data1.drop(['LogFiT', 'LogS'], axis=1)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 42)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
randomforest = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1)
selector = SelectFromModel(randomforest)
features_important = selector.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
model = randomforest.fit(features_important, y_train)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
clf_rf = RandomForestRegressor()
parameters = {"n_estimators":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 50], "max_depth":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10,  15]}
grid_search_cv_clf = GridSearchCV(model, parameters, cv=5)
grid_search_cv_clf.fit(features_important, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
y_pred = grid_search_cv_clf.predict(features_important)
r2_score(y_train, y_pred)
grid_search_cv_clf.best_params_
best_clf = grid_search_cv_clf.best_estimator_
best_clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

The error:
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 22 and input n_features is 114

```
feature_importances = best_clf.feature_importances_
feature_importances_df = pd.DataFrame({'features':list(X_train),
                                      'feature_importances':feature_importances})
importances = feature_importances_df.sort_values('feature_importances', ascending=False)
importances.head(20)
```

This gives an error: 
ValueError: arrays must all be same length

I understand that the problem is different number of features in features_important (X_train) and x_test, but I don't know how to fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the columns of X_test:

```
X_test_filtered = X_test.iloc[:,selector.get_support()]
best_clf.score(X_test_filtered, y_test)
```

On the second bit of code instead, I think this is what you wanted, but correct me if I'm wrong:

```
feature_importances = best_clf.feature_importances_
feature_importances_df = pd.DataFrame({'features': X_test_filtered.columns.values),
                                  'feature_importances':feature_importances})
importances = feature_importances_df.sort_values('feature_importances', ascending=False)
importances.head(20)
```

EDIT - I edited the method as I realized that the selector returns an array and not a series. Using get_support to get the mask should work

Comment: I followed your advice and wrote '''X_test_filtered = X_test[features_important.columns]
best_clf.score(X_test_filtered, y_test)''' But it gives an AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: I edited the answer - I had not realized that fit_transform returned an array instead of a Series.

Comment: You're welcome. If the solution works you can mark the answer as correct, and it will not appear as unresolved and award points :)

Comment: Maybe you can also help me to calculate leave-one-out cross-validation for this model?